# Обязательно ли использовать класс-адаптер если GridLayout надо заполнить 144мя картинками?

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

[image: скрин игрового поле]Помогите пожалуйста! Пишу игру **Paopao**, и игровое поле этой игры состоит из 144 картинок (16 столбцов, 9 строк). **И картинки размещаются в GridLayout**, но не уверен что такой способ не ухудшает производительность приложения. В связи с этим подумал может мне **обязательно нужно использовать адаптер**. Пожалуйста поделитесь знанием. Не судите строго, я новичок пока что.

Comment: Когда все ячейки одновременно видны на экране, использование адаптера вряд ли улучшит производительность, но может упростить сам код приложения.

Comment: не обязательно, использовать можете хоть 9 LinearLayout